# How to get graphical display when executing commands as another user, through terminal?

Tags: command-line

In my terminal, I did

```
 $su nextuser
```

and logged in to that account. Now, when I try to open a text file in the home directory of that user by

```
$gedit test.c
```

I get

```
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

How can I use the graphical text editor to display files on the new user's account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As root, run

```
echo $DISPLAY
xhost local:nextuser
```

Then

```
su - nextuser
export DISPLAY=<the value got from echo $DISPLAY above>
(or SET DISPLAY.. if export does not work)
```

And you are good to go. :)

Comment: `xhost +si:localuser:nextuser` did it for me. can be checked with `xhost`.

Answer (score 4):

## Running Graphical Commands from Another User's Shell

The [sux [image: Install sux]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sux) command (see [`man sux`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sux.1.html)) takes care of this for you, and takes the same syntax as `su`.

```
sux - nextuser
gedit test.c
```

This will automatically ensure the `.Xauthority` is correct, so you don't have to run any commands to manually authorize anything.

Graphical applications tend to write configuration files in your home directory, and if you run them as another user while preserving `$HOME`, they'll attempt to write configuration files as that user, in *your* home directory. This will result in failing to write the configuration, or the configuration getting messed up for the original user (or some combination of the two). **That's why it's advisable to use the `-` flag with `sux` (or `su`) when running graphical applications.** (For `sudo`, you can instead use [graphical frontends](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) like `gksu`/`gksudo` and `kdesudo`.)

## Running Graphical Commands Directly as Another User

You can use [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html) in *su-mode* (with the `-w` flag) to run the command as another user (with the `-u` flag):

```
gksu -w -u nextuser gedit test.c
```

However, you *might* still have to run `xhost local:nextuser` first (as you detailed in [your quite good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/168983/22949)) for this to work. It's less likely to need that if you use *sudo-mode*, but then you can only do it if you're an administrator (and you'll be authenticating with *your* password rather than `nextuser`'s password, as `sudo` rather than `su` is the backend):

```
gksu -u nextuer gedit test.c
```

## Running the Terminal (Not Just the Shell) as Another User

You may just want to run the graphical Terminal program (that the shell runs "inside") as the other user. Once it's running, graphical programs launched from it will work seamlessly as well.

You can use the same methods described above for running `gedit` as the other user.

```
gksu -w -u nextuser gnome-terminal
```

```
gksu -u nextuser gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-p` option with *su* to preserve environment variables including `DISPLAY`; alternately set it explicitly with `export` or prefix it on a per command basis.

Comment: I tried that. But then the new user's home folder is the old user's one itself. As in, when you type just    cd, the terminal takes me to the old user's home folder. I'm talking in case of using -p. I did not understand what your other suggestions meant.