# Connect to server PC with GUI for multiple users

Tags: rdp, multi-user

Problem: Need to use one ubuntu machine(main machine) by two people, one will use it by connecting the machine to a monitor and the other will have his own windows/ubuntu machine and connect to main machine remotely. Both should get GUI interface and different workspace for each separately.

I have one single desktop machine which is used by my colleague. I wish to use the same machine for working on my application development. But the catch is I would be requiring the GUI also.

I understand that there should be an RDP server running in my desktop and I need an RDP client to do this. But I am not sure whether this will work as my colleague will still be working on the desktop with GNOME and I need a GUI for my remote connection separately.

I wish to get some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: If you wish to use RDP, then you would need a RDP server like xrdp while for VNC you would need a VNC server. A multi user setup with their own GUI session is possible to be setup using both. What OS/version are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not saying I wish to use RDP; I said that is what I know. When I connect with a VNC client, the GUI I am using will be directly of the server machine and the person using the server machine cannot use the server machine independently. I want both the users to use the machine independently. Kindly let me know whatever way it can be done? 

Not sure I am explaining this properly! Hope you get the problem.

Server will be an Ubuntu 18.04. Remote client can be anything windows/ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need 1) a full remote graphical desktop environment, or would it be enough to get 2) windows from the server machine onto the native graphical desktop environment of the client machine? RDP and VNC provide 1) and the simpler SSH provides 2). My experience is that SSH might be easier to get working and it might be good enough. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398).