# Using an old laptop running Ubuntu as monitor

Tags: windows, laptop, monitor

I would like to use an old laptop as a monitor for a PC. The PC is currently running Windows 10, but I'm looking to install Ubuntu 18 on it alongside it.
I'm also looking to install Ubuntu 18 on the laptop.

Is there any way that this could be made to work with either OS, or even both?

Comment: In my limited experience, laptops usually have output video ports, but do not have input video ports. That kind of design makes your request problematic.

Comment: A simpler approach than Remmina is to connect via a local network (ethernet) and install Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS `lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and the program package **`openssh-server`** in the PC and the same Lubuntu into the laptop and then connect to it with **`ssh -X`** in order to run graphical application programs and see them on your laptop's screen. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398). (Lubuntu is a light-weight flavour of Ubuntu, so things will be smoother and faster.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for remote desktop capability:  https://remmina.org/

Comment: While that is very interesting, its not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something much less elaborate. I wouldn't mind having a video cable running between my desktop and the old laptop for example, without anything but the video signal going between the two.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible (without, possibly, some expensive, special purpose, hardware). And what about keyboard/mouse?

Comment: I have an external keyboard and mouse that I use with the desktop and the laptop when I'm at home.

Answer (score 1):

Since laptops don't have video inputs, either you can

- Open the laptop to expose the screen connector and manually add an input connector to the [ribbon cable](https://www.laptopscreen.com/blog/tag/lcd-extension-cable/) from the laptop motherboard to the screen
- Use software to accept the video from the other PC and display it on your laptop screen. A [review of some of those apps is shown here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-laptop-like-external-monitor/), or you could consider [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) or [ssh -x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398), as previously mentioned.