# Ubuntu base linux distro for windows 7 alternative as windows gets slow for pentium 4 dual core cpu

Tags: window-manager

I have an old pc (i think I've got it somewhere in 2007 when I was in middle school).

this pc was my only computer untill 3 or 4 years ago but it was getting soooo slow with windows 7 installed on it.
after that when I've got this laptop the pc turned into a media storage where I only keep my movies and animes. and watch them on it. sometimes I use it to share some big files between my laptop and the pc itself. its basically a storage/server/ftp or something like that now.

thats my usage background!

and here are the specs that I've got from `dxdiag`:
cpu: Intell(R) Pentium 4 CPU 3.00GHz (2CPUs), ~3.0GHz
Memory: 4096MB RAM
Page file: 961MB used, 4665MB available
System manufacturer: OEM
system Model: OEM
BIOS: Phoenix - AwardBIOS v6.00PG
Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7601)

thats all.

as I said before, this PC gets really slow somethimes I had to wait like 2 to 3 minutes (sometimes even up to 5 minutes) just to open up a chrome browser!! and even after opening it, it was really slow.

so I've just go ahead and disabled all the unnecessary graphics and animations and it looks like a windows server 2008 right now (in the graphical perspective of course), and its way better right now, the google chrome is opens up in less that 30 to 60 seconds, but its still slow as some times the mouse moves like its processing a big amount of data while there is nothing open.

i watched the task manager and saw there are tones of processes that i know its from windows like svhost and other things so I have decided to get a linux os on it and see whats better or not.

- I want a linux based on ubuntu or debian (bc i have a background with them and comfortable with their terminals)
- It should be light weight
- It should be beautiful
- It should be able to work with networks and sharing stuff (i have a windows laptop so it should be able to communicate with it on network sharing and so on)
- **and most importantly it should be very fast** so that I could save up some resource for my media stuff.
- But if the UI beauty is causing problems with its performance scratch it from the list.

thats my question.

**Is there any version or flavour of Ubuntu, that would work well for me in this computer with these usage and preferences specifications?**

I've heard about lubuntu and ubuntu mate, but they seems to be both very heavy as their new versions look very graphical. i dont want so much graphics a decent level. (like I want better graphic than windows xp but if as good (or not) as win 7 thats cool with me).

Recomment me some of youre knowledge Linux GURUs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic    Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here.

Comment: fyi:  in 2006 the Core2Duo replaced pentium 4's, and most P4's I've come across as only x86 (not 64 bit) which does limit your options somewhat.  You can download & try ubuntu before you install (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0), and this applies to official flavors of Ubuntu too - https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: Please consider using Ubuntu Server on this computer, and vote for reopening.

Comment: @mfrHoujat I would suggest to install Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS on it and refresh the thermo-interface between cooler and CPU. High CPU temperature may lead to system freezes. Also run RAM tester on the system (Memtest86+ from any Linux live media) to exclude possible RAM problems.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu family desktop systems

Please find out and tell us if your computer can run a 64-bit operating system. For one and a half more year you can run for example Lubuntu and Ubuntu MATE version 18.04.x LTS, but after the end of life in April 2021 there will be no supported 32-bit Ubuntu family desktop operating system (with a graphical desktop environment).

### Ubuntu Server

But there is Ubuntu Server and its 18.04.1 LTS version will be supported for a longer period, for at least 5 years, maybe even 10 years, so at least until April 2023, and by that time maybe you should allow your old computer to retire.

Ubuntu Server comes without any graphical desktop environment, only a text screen. It should run fast on your old computer, and you can easily connect to it via the network.

#### Graphical window manager in Ubuntu Server

It is not generally recommended for a server, but possible and maybe suitable in your case, to install basic graphics with a window manager rather than a full graphical desktop environment. It would have a light foot-print and might work fast enough in your old computer.

In the server you need an ssh server, for example `openssh-server` and at least some basic X tools, for example `xinit` and `fluxbox` (and the programs and libraries that they need). You must also install the application programs that you want to run, I suggest `xterm` and the graphical application programs that you want to run.

You start a [local] graphical session with `startx`

See more details at the following links,

[old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/)

[What is the simplest way to have remote GUI access to Ubuntu 16.04 “server” from Ubuntu 16.04 “desktop”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)

---

[Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)

Answer (score 0):

Very short answer, based on my experience:

- Puppy linux
- Tiny core
- Lubuntu
- Xubuntu

*(further information on web)*

The first two are very **light** but far less customizable and have ugly UI.
Third and forth are more **complete**, customizable have beautiful UI and being ubuntu-based you can lightweight them by yourself.