# Browse a website from my personal computer as if I were using my server

Tags: server, internet, vpn, browser, remote-access

I would like to be able to access websites from my laptop computer as if I were using a limited-access server that is connected to my university's network. I want to do this to access scientific articles while working from other places.

The university has a VPN system, but it does not allow me to browse articles as if I were located in my office and connected to the university network. I also cannot use sci-hub for this (for instance, usually directly outputs a .PDF from a given article and does not allow you to navigate through the page of the journal).

Note that I can only connect to this server if I am securely connected to the university's VPN, in a way that the only way to use such a system is to have access to both the server and to the VPN. Also, I am the server admin.

Would you know if this is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can `ssh` to your server you can use it as a *socks proxy*.

Comment: `ssh -X` and you can run graphical application programs (e.g. a web browser). See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398). But the graphics will be slower than if you have direct access to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses! I was able to make it work by following these [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel#step-5-(optional)-%E2%80%94-troubleshooting-getting-through-firewalls) to open a SOCKSv5 tunnel and change the Proxy configuration on my alternative browser! It worked like a charm!