# Install GUI on Ubuntu Server and remotely control it from MacOS or Windows?

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, vnc, docker, xserver

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (intend to upgrade to 19.10 soon).

This is a remote server, no keyboard or display attached. I have never used a GUI on this machine, only connected remotely through SSH and control all processes and services from there.

Is it possible to install some kind of GUI or desktop environment on this server, which I can then control and use remotely from a non-Ubuntu system? In particular from MacOS, although from a Windows 10 PC would also suffice.

I guess there are different ways to do this, perhaps an "X window" or "X server" (although I'm not even sure that that is) or using some VNC-like approach, or some Docker container maybe?

I have zero experience with this so if my approach is all wrong and there is a better way to do this, I'd highly appreciate any suggestions or pointers.

Comment: Why would you need a GUI?

Comment: @vidarlo For several reasons, e.g. because I want to run a browser and interactively perform certain online tasks from that machine. And because I want to run some cryptocurrency GUI wallets on there.

Comment: Try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398).