# 2 Ubuntu 19.10 PCs cannot share desktop, mediafiles and cups printer

Tags: networking, printing, 19.10, vnc, sharing

1 Intel i3-8100/32GB pc ("FujitsuServer" with ip 192.168.88.10) and 1 Intel i5-8350/8GB laptop ("Laptop-A" with ip 192.168.88.22) both with fresh Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 installs.

I have enabled Desktop sharing and Media sharing on the PC. 
I have installed a Brother printer successfully via USB, works fine. I can access localhost:631 and see CUPS, printer sharing is enabled.

I can PING both computers from each other.

PROBLEM:

- Laptop, when using Remmina, I cannot access the pc
  via vnc, "FujitsuServer.local" does nothing, no connection can be
  made.
- Lapto, file manager > Network I can see "FUJITSUSERVER"
  but I get a "Connection refused" error.
- I can find the shared printer on the laptop, but I cannot print anything to it.
- The cups webUI of the PC is also not accessible via the laptop (going to
  192.168.88.10:631 leads to a timeout).

I even tried connecting both directly with each other via a networkcable, assigning IP addresses manually. PING works. But just like with a router between them, nothing else.

How is sharing suppose to work?

Comment: Maybe you can start with a simple way to connect from the laptop to the PC by installing `openssh-server` into the PC and logging in remotely with `ssh` and transferring files with`sftp` or FileZilla or networks access via the file browser. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398) may help. Then, later on, you can start with more advanced stuff like Remmina and/or VNC. Edit: You need only install openssh-server (not Fluxbox, xinit and xterm) because you have the Budgie graphic DE already.

Comment: I only want to use the default options of Ubuntu to share desktop, files and printer.
All the options you mention are more advanced AND are meant to securely access PCs over the internet. Which is not my usecase, as I explained in my question.
Ubuntu has 2 simple switches to enable desktop sharing and media folder sharing. That's all I need. Same goes for Printer sharing.

Comment: Well, I suggested a method that is easy to use. It happens to provide secure access too. -- Let us hope that someone else will see your question and help you with the 'default options' of Ubuntu.

Comment: My point is, I would like to use the features that come by default with Ubuntu. 
You are suggesting to ignore those features and use different solutions. 

Is there something wrong with the built-in functionality, since it is not working for me? I prefer to solve the problems instead of letting them be and go for something else.

Comment: I don't know how to use those features that come by default with Ubuntu because I use the `ssh` tools for networking. I know that other people use other tools, and I hope and think that someone, who uses those features and tools tools will chip in and help you.

Comment: If you think it would help you (make your question more attractive), I can remove my comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to screen share within your LAN inside your network between Linux devices, use NoMachine. It is way faster than any other service and user friendly options to change host resolution and change screen size to make it usable on your client screen.

However if you need support online like TeamViewer, use AnyDesk.

I now use my PC or NAS by simply using NoMachine on my laptop. Giving me access to a full pc while on the couch.