# Do I have to run headless if I want to access my ubuntu machine from windows?

Tags: nvidia, ssh, remote-desktop, headless

I have a PC running ubuntu and also a NVIDIA Xavier running ubuntu.
One is a desktop and the other one a embedded machine. Both are at my office.

I would like to access them from my windows PC at home.
Now, I can access them through SSH (and super Putty) without problem.

However I am having problems trying to access them graphically through Microsoft Remote Desktop.

My question is, if I want to use remote desktop to access them do they have to be running headlessly (without a screen here at the office)?

Does Xserver not get started if the ubuntu machine is not connected to a screen?

Comment: No, you running headless should not be needed. Have you looked at [this post](https://kamarada.github.io/en/2020/04/29/remote-desktop-connection-to-linux-from-windows-using-the-xrdp-server/)? (Yes I realize it's for another disto but it's probably easily adaptable) NOTE: you will likely need to use a VPN or port forwarding for it to work over WAN.

Comment: Ubuntu uses VNC (Vino server) as remote desktop. Windows RDP client may not be able to connect to VNC. Try the famous mRemoteNG Windows program https://mremoteng.org/

Comment: Remote desktop will work for you most of the times. Centrify might be an issue for you if you use it to authenticate.

Comment: You can make things simpler. Log in via 'ssh -X` and then graphical programs will work for you (if you have software in Windows to take care of X). See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398).