# How to remotely login to a locally started Lightdm session

Tags: lightdm, remote-desktop, vnc, rdp

Is it possible on ubuntu to start a session locally (with lightdm) and then re open it from another pc (running ubuntu) ?

I need also that the local screen remains locked (for confidentiality reasons).

I am looking for the same behavior than RDP have on a windows PC.

I am running xubuntu 20.04

Xrdp only re open a rdp session, not a local one. x11vnc keeps the local screen mirrored with the remote one, so it does not work for me.

Comment: Is it necessary to login to a locally started Lightdm session? Or would it be OK to log in to the computer and select a [graphical] ssh session with `ssh -X`? In that case you can install `openssh-server` in the remote computer, which will serve as an ssh server, and go ahead. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)

Comment: Locally started session is necessary. I am trying to replace windows on workstations.