# How to set up a remote server with GUI over SSH?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, x11-forwarding

I have installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS on a PC that I intend to use as a media server and compute node. Atop Ubuntu server, I have installed the default gnome desktop. I am able connect to this server using SSH from other machines.

**I want to be able to:**

Remotely access the whole GUI of the server.

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from) which seems to be running only apps, not the entire display of the server.

I do not want to use VNC as I will be using this server over the internet.

**What is the simplest way to achieve this?**

Comment: Use VNC and tunnel it over SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server will need xrdp installed and set up if you do not want to use VNC.
a guide is [on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-protocol-using-xrdp-on-ubuntu-22-04) including configuring requiring passwords

Remmina client will connect to VNC and RDP so you can test over LAN.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this as soon as I can and update this.