# Installing DE on Ubuntu Server gives me an error that prevents me from reaching the CLI

Tags: command-line, server, desktop-environments

I'm getting this weird issue when trying to install a DE on my Ubuntu Server VM. We made a VM in Hyper-V. I installed Ubuntu Server without issue. When I try to install a DE, I keep getting the issue in the image. After rebooting I see this, no DE, just a CLI displaying this error. If I try Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2, I can see the CLI to enter commands for a second then this error comes back every time, so I am unable to use the CLI. I tried reinstalling. I tried Ubuntu's Desktop Gnome and Xfce. I tried installing with apt and tasksel. I get the same error each time. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Image of error]

Comment: You've provided no details as to what Ubuntu Server release you're using, nor what package(s) you used to install the DE; for specific help you need to provide specific details.

Comment: The image you provided shows no errors. It shows three ordinary notifications and a single non-critical warning). Maybe you didn't allocate enough memory )or video memory) to the VM. Maybe your cloud-init file has unusual requirements. Maybe you simply aren't waiting long enough for Plymouth to finish. Maybe you are doing something unsupported. Lots of possibilities. Unfortunately, there is not yet enough detail to offer useful advice.

Comment: Maybe you need not install a full desktop environment into your Ubuntu Server. Instead you could install a simple window manager, for example according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398).