# How do I use `pycharm` from the terminal using `ssh`?

Tags: ssh, 22.04, pycharm

I want to use `pycharm` and make my own AI. However, I can only `ssh` into my server. Is there a way to use `pycharm` through the `ssh` interface?

I've tried searching around online for an answer but came back with nothing.

Also, my apologies if this is the wrong message board for this question. I still don't fully understand the rules of Stack Overflow/Ask Ubuntu.

I have tried running it using `pycharm` and `pycharm-community` to see if some kind of interface would pop up but again no cigar.

Comment: sorry i meant 22.04 the newest one my mistake

Comment: Please update the question with all new information. Do not put it in comments. Also, Desktop or Server? Perhaps add the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest way to have remote GUI access to Ubuntu 16.04 “server” from Ubuntu 16.04 “desktop”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from)

Comment: Please clarify "AI"?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xorg, then it is possible to run graphical applications over SSH using **X11 forwarding**. However, this is *old technology*, it is slow and, in particular, very insecure. You should not attempt this.

Instead, you may **mount your network directory** on the local file. Unfortunatelly, `sshfs` is not further developped, so prefer to use samba or rclone. Then, you can access and work on these files with your local installation of Pycharm.

Alternatively, you could **synchronize the files** locally and work on the local copy, then sync the files back. This ensures you will never be slowed down or even interrupted due to network issues, and you can even work off line. The simplest (and still reliable) way to synchronize between your local drive and the server is to use a tool like `rsync` or `rclone`. (Simpler, but not reliable and slower, is to simply copy/paste files back and to the server - not recommended). A more advanced way involves the use of a versioning system such as git, cvs or mercurial.