# Stuck on "username" login screen at startup

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with GNOME 42.9 (see full `inxi -F` below) and `gdm3`.

Recently, when I try to login to the computer using an attached screen (as opposed to just `ssh`), the login screen does not show the selection of usernames.  Instead it displays a box with a "username" in it.  But if I type in any real username and press enter, it just refreshes the same screen.  It does not move to a screen requesting a password.

This happens with any username, including real ones and ones that I made up.

I uninstalled `gdm3` and reinstalled it.  But that didn't fix it.

Not sure this is a helpful piece of info, but I can `ssh` in, start a `vnc` session, and the remote session will work and lock/unlock properly.

```
System:
  Host: hp-plex-ubuntu Kernel: 5.15.0-87-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 18E7 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Hewlett-Packard v: L01 v02.21 date: 12/17/2013
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-4570 bits: 64 type: MCP cache:
    L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1819 min/max: 800/3600 cores: 1: 2295 2: 2295 3: 1890
    4: 798
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
    driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.9 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: VIA USB Dongle type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-87-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I217-LM driver: e1000e
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a0:48:1c:a1:5c:a4
  IF-ID-1: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A
  IF-ID-2: virbr0 state: down mac: 52:54:00:68:82:82
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.51 TiB used: 729.54 GiB (47.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: SanDisk model: SD6SB1M-128G-1006 size: 119.24 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD15EADS-00P8B0
    size: 1.36 TiB
  ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Fit
    size: 29.82 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 91.11 GiB used: 38.16 GiB (41.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
  ID-2: /boot size: 451.6 MiB used: 188.7 MiB (41.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 196.9 MiB used: 114 MiB (57.9%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 15.2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/sda5
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 330 Uptime: 2d 18h 58m Memory: 23.38 GiB used: 4.3 GiB (18.4%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS in a workstation with a separate monitor, and I could log in as expected this morning. Please tell me some more details: Did it work before and stopped working recently? Or did this happen directly after installing or upgrading from a previous version? If login used to work but stopped working, can you remember that you did something, or that you noticed something happening just before or in the working session before login stopped working? What happens after reboot?

Comment: It did work before and stop working.  The recently part I can't attest to -- I usually ssh or vnc into it, only using it for a direct HDMI connection to the TV in limited circumstances.  It definitely worked within the past 2 months.  But I had multiple ssh-based upgrades in the interim.  Reboot changes nothing except, for a brief second it shows the normal login screen with the usernames available, then immediately switches to the "username" only box.

Comment: This makes me think that the problem is caused by an upgrade of some program package. But you can still run the computer via a remote connection. Have you tried to make the system completely up to date via ssh: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` ? I suggest that you {try / try again}, maybe you get an error or warning message, maybe it solves the problem. Anyway, before doing more advanced things, I suggest that you backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (personal files ...).

Comment: After the backup you can install a second desktop environment, for example the program package `lubuntu-desktop` or `xubuntu-desktop` with all the default tools that come with it. It will be almost impossible to remove the second desktop environment without damage to the first one, but they can live side by side (and occupy some drive space).  An alternative is a simple window manager according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398), and run `startx` to get graphics locally.

Comment: Definitely not trying to change the entire Desktop Environments.  I am hoping to fix the problem in the first instance.  If that doesn't work, I would change Display Managers to `lightdm`.